# Remove all occurrences of property

Tags: javascript, properties

I have code like this

```
for (var j=0;j<100;j++){
    ...
    data[j].property1 = something;
}
```

and now I want to remove all ocurences of `property1`. something like this

```
remove data[]['property1']
```

is there easy way to do that, or must I ensure it by cycle?

Comment: Run this in a loop
`delete data[j]['property1'];`

Comment: You could refer http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ 
This is an incredibly detailed blog explaining how delete works

Comment: You may enjoy to put the loop inside a function `remove_property(data, 'property1')`

Comment: Why don't u like cycling? :D

Comment: @donkeydown And what is remove_property?

Comment: @harsha A function they define to encapsulate the looping and deletion, so they can reuse it.

Comment: @harsha I mean something less demanding for my machine ;-) for example if the loop is 1000000x. I just only searching for fastest way

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : I understand that it's a function. But will simply writing `remove_property(data, 'property1')` explain everything?

Comment: @donkeydown you should learn to read properly and give right answears. not meant in bad ;-)

Comment: @koubin So what exactly are you asking? Whether or not it's possible to do it without a loop? If so, the answer is no.

Comment: @harsha It's a comment, it doesn't have to explain everything (or anything, for that matter). I assumed they were simply saying "It might be a good idea to put whatever logic in a function."

Comment: @AnthonyGrist please read again to understand question. maybe you can assign cycle = loop

Comment: @koubin The question is poorly written and not at all clear. If it was possible for me to understand precisely what you want by reading the question that would have happened one of the many times I've done so already, so telling me to "read again to understand" is absolutely useless. Also not sure what you mean by "maybe you can assign cycle = loop".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'm not native English speaker. sometime I don't use exact term. if you read last sentence in my question, there is "cycle". you can repace this word by "loop" (assign cycle = loop). I think my question is very clear. so give me -1 is baseless. btw what is unintelligible on my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it in 1 step.
You must do it in a loop:

```
function remove_property(arr, property_name)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delete arr[i][property_name];
  }
}

remove_property(data, 'property1');
```

Or maybe you can put your property in another array and then delete this other array directly.

```
var property1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  property1[i] = something;
}
...
delete property1; // 1 step
```

Comment: I know, that wasn't for you actually. I guess the answer for you is: There is no way to do it in 1 step.